# Change the definition of an interpolated function

Tags: function-construction, finite-element-method, interpolation

I have a little question.
I used the built in function 'NDEigensystem' to solve a differential equation; the results of this operation give me several functions; so I type in imput one of this like:

```
funcs[1][2][3]
```

and the output is the following:
[image]

To evaluate this x-dependent function, in a particular value of x, I have to use the following:

```
funcs[1][2][3]/.x->0.5
```

Is there a way to create a new function that has explicit x-dependence like:

```
newfuncs[1][2][3][x]
```

Thanks for any tips and helps!

There is my code that find the functions mentioned previously:

```
For[i = 0, i < passiL + 1, i++,For[j = 0, j < passiw + 1, j++,H:=(-Laplacian[#,{x}]+V[x, a, Lin + incrementoL i] #) &; {{energies[1][i][j],energies[2][i][j]},{funcs[1][i][j],funcs[2][i][j]}}=NDEigensystem[{H@\[Psi][x],DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x]==0,True]},\[Psi][x],{x,0,a+Lin+incrementoL i + win + incrementow j },dim,Method->{"SpatialDiscretization"->{"FiniteElement",\"MeshOptions" ->"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}},"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST","Interval"->{0,a+Lin + incrementoL i + win + incrementow j }}}]]]
```

I don't think it is all necessary, but I post all of it.

Comment: You mention that these functions come from `NDEigensystem[]`; you might only need to specify its second argument in the form `{u}` instead of `{u[t, x]}` to get what you want. (And if you want a more definite answer, you need to disclose the code that generates these functions of yours.)

Comment: Ok, I edit the question so you can see my code to evaluate that functions.

Answer (score 5):

I can't get your code to work due to missing brackets. However, if we pull an example out of Help we can work with an alternative.

```
ℒ = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}];
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[ℒ, 
   u[x, y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, 4];
```

Looking at one of the funs we see

```
funs[[4]]
```

[image]

Now to get something more usable which is what I think you want we can do

```
f4 = Head[funs[[4]]]
```

which strips off the square brackets at the end and gives

[image]

We now have a name for our interpolation function and we can put back the square brackets with the notation we need.

```
Plot3D[f4[x, y], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}]
```

[image]

Does that help?

Comment: Yes! It helps me! Thank you.Is there a difference between the interpolating function with '[x,y]' and without '[x,y]'?

Comment: What I was trying to say in the comments to @Lorenzo is that if you instead evaluate `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[ℒ, u, {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, 4];`, you wouldn't need to fiddle with heads.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. My question is if there are differences between thath two type of interpolating functions.

Comment: No difference at all to the interpolation function.